# Parsing JSON data from an XML web service in Android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I have an XML web service. I want to parse this XML  and I want to store in an separate textviews. The following is an XML content, and I have finished getting it in a `String` variable.

```
{
    "30_year_rate": 4.25,
    "30_year_pi": 196.78,
    "30_year_apr": 4.375,
    "20_year_rate": 4.375,
    "20_year_pi": 250.37,
    "20_year_apr": 4.5,
    "15_year_rate": 3.75,
    "15_year_pi": 290.89,
    "15_year_apr": 3.875,
    "10_year_rate": 3.625,
    "10_year_pi": 397.89,
    "10_year_apr": 3.75,
    "5_year_arm": 2.75,
    "5_year_pi": 163.3,
    "5_year_apr": 2.875,
    "7_year_arm": 3,
    "7_year_pi": 168.64,
    "7_year_apr": 3.125,
    "3_year_arm": 4,
    "3_year_pi": 190.97,
    "3_year_apr": 4.125,
    "5_year_io_arm": "N/A",
    "5_year_io_pi": "N/A",
    "5_year_io_apr": "N/A",
    "QuoteID": 1449,
    "Licensed": "N"
}
```

How can I parse this data? I want to convert it to a JSON object and retrieve it, or any other reasonable approach.

Comment: What now? This isn't XML but JSON. It is a JSON encoded string. What is the question here?

Comment: sir, actually iam doing an ksoap webservice to access an .net webservice and, i get the result as <string> {"year":1990,"month":04 ... <string>, i stored that above group of lines in an string variable, and now i want to parse it, how can i do this?

Comment: Do you want to re-write json parser by not using jsonobject?

Answer (score 1):

If what you're getting back from the webservice is the string above, then you already have a JSON string.  To create an object that can retrieve information from it, use something like [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(your_string_variable);
double thirtyYearRate = object.getDouble("30_year_rate");
String licensed = object.getString("Licensed");
```

etc.

You might (will) run into some issues where you try to pull a `double` from a JSON field that contains a string; i.e., the "N/A" fields above.  You'll likely have to pull them out as strings and then try to parse `double`s from them, and if the parsing throws an exception, you'll know it's a string.

Alternately, you could look into JSON binding with something like Jackson, which apparently [runs on Android](http://supersabrams.com/blog/?p=81).

Answer (score 0):

To parse JSON, you could use the built in JSONObject [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) Or [Json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) if you use an old version of android.

To parse XML, use [XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). A sample can be found here: [Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)